How enforce the format 7807 error response in a .NET project?
I am working a .NET project and seeing a strange behavior on how the framework handles the return of a BadRequest with extra information in a Controller class.
Sometimes it is able to return the JSON in the format following RFC 7807 (which is the expected scenario). But it can also return a plain text or even a different format that seems just a exception deserialized.
I have some examples of each behavior:
var response = await _mediator.Send(request);
if (!response.Succeeded)
{
    // not return in the RFC 7807 format, but the "Error" content is converted to a JSON 
    return BadRequest(response.Error); 

    // returns the RFC 7807 format
    return BadRequest(); 

    // returns a plain text with the message "Hello"
    return BadRequest("Hello"); 

    // returns in the RFC 7807 format
    return BadRequest(new ProblemDetails 
    {
       Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
       Title = "Bad Request",
       Detail = response.Error.Message,
       Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    });
}
return response.ToHttpResult();

Is there a way to force to return the error following the RFC 7807 without explicitly use the ProblemDetails?

It seems that your are using ControllerBase.BadRequest, so the overload accepting object will use the passed object as the error passed to client (via the BadRequestObjectResult).
Possibly the easiest way to handle this would be to use ControllerBase.Problem directly instead of manually wrapping it into BadRequest:
[HttpGet("/problem")]
public IActionResult GetProblem() => Problem("Hello World Problem", statusCode: 400);  

If you want the BadRequestObjectResult to behave like ProblemDetails then you can create custom IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult>. For example to get you started:
class MyObjectResultExecutor : ObjectResultExecutor
{
    private readonly ProblemDetailsFactory _problemDetailsFactory;

    public MyObjectResultExecutor(
        ProblemDetailsFactory problemDetailsFactory,
        OutputFormatterSelector formatterSelector,
        IHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory writerFactory,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IOptions<MvcOptions> mvcOptions) : base(formatterSelector, writerFactory, loggerFactory, mvcOptions)
    {
        _problemDetailsFactory = problemDetailsFactory;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
    {
        // turn BadRequestObjectResult into ProblemDetails the way you need too
        if (result is BadRequestObjectResult badRequestResult)
        {
            var actual = _problemDetailsFactory.CreateProblemDetails(context.HttpContext,
                400);
            actual.Extensions.Add("error", badRequestResult.Value);
            
            return base.ExecuteAsync(context, new ObjectResult(actual)
            {
                StatusCode = actual.Status,
            });
        }
        return base.ExecuteAsync(context, result);
    }
}

And register it in the DI:
builder.Services.AddTransient<IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult>, MyObjectResultExecutor>();

Also you can use the ProblemDetailsOptions.CustomizeProblemDetails to perform some magic via context features as suggested in the docs.
